# C files get an error using the NDK

Tags: android, service, bluetooth

I have been given a program written in C, and have been asked to use the functions from the program in a new Android application. I have been following the tutorials of the NDK, but have hit a wall. I think all that is left is compiling or linking my C files, but I'm not sure. I have installed the SDK, NDK, Eclipse, Cygwin, and Sequoyah ( I haven't used Sequoyah yet and don't really know where it comes into play ).

I have used the ndk-build command, but am not sure what I am should be expecting. This is a screenshot of my Cygwin terminal.
[image]

This is a screen shot of my NWPTest.c file. All of the fields defined in the .h file come up as errors. I feel like this is an error that should go away once I compile the code.
[image]

BYTE and WORD etc. declarations here:

[image]

This is a screen shot of the NWPTest.h file. BYTE and WORD declarations are also coming up as errors, which is something I do not understand. 
[image]

This screen shot basically shows the last thing as the last one, but I'm confused how some of the BYTEs are errors and some are not:
[image]

EDIT

Here is my Android.mk file. Just to clarify, I was given the entire C project, and was told to make it an Android application. I have no experience with C.
[image]

Comment: Was going to say - did you `#include "defines.h"` in your respective header sources?

Comment: Another thing - can you show the Android.mk that you used in your ndk-build?

Comment: FWIW the build of the C source using `ndk-build` worked and dumped the library into the project's *lib/armeabi* directory at the root of your project's workspace. That looks ok. If you did have errors - it would have been flagged in your output on the cygwin terminal.

Comment: Just added it to the original post.

Comment: Well, you can check, there should be a *libRelayAPI.so* in your *lib/armeabi* directory of your **Java** project . So all would be left now I guess is to build a JNI to interface that library.

Comment: Yes, there is a RelayAPI within lib/armeabi. How would I go about building a JNI?

Comment: You have not done this before have you? WE're not doing the work for you, you need to read up, try it out, play with it, understand it,[tutorial](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html)

Comment: No, I have not. I'm not trying to have work be done for me. I have read plenty of tutorials and at this point in the tutorials the C files don't have errors, and the writer of the tutorial just moves on.

Comment: Also, the majority of the tutorials have the user write new C code, which is slightly different than the position that I am in. If I followed the tutorial which you just sent me, it will not help me with the error I have. Nevertheless, I will start a new project now and follow the tutorial you sent me, hopefully it will clear something up for me.

Comment: that's NDK/JNI tutorial to understand how to use it with Android.

Comment: Haha ok, you're right. I couldn't find an Activity class in the examples. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your problem is that Eclipse doesn't know about the include path for the ndk C header files; however that should not really matter since ndk-build appears to have built your native library.  Though if your C-aware eclipse setup is being obstinate and refusing to build the rest of your project with "errors" in the C files, then you will have to either fix the include path or tell eclipse to ignore the C files as it does when not aware of C.

Of more concern would be whatever is causing an error in Operations.java - that will prevent you from building an apk.

Comment: Thanks, but operations.java just had a missing semi-colon and had been fixed since the screen shot.

Comment: What do you mean by fix the include path?

Comment: You need to tell it where to find the android ndk header files, probably somewhere under the project menu.  But determining that path is messy, since it depends on the android platform you are targeting.  Most likely, you should either use an ndk-aware CDT that handles this automatically(?), or get eclipse to ignore C files, either via some option or at an extreme by removing the CDT.

Comment: Well, the NDK path has been set to the folder where I extracted all of my NDK files. Is that different than the 'android ndk header files' path? I also have the most up-to-date CDT. I got it through Eclipse (Help->Install New Software) then typed galileo and checked the C/C++ Development tools. I just did this again a few seconds ago and it says that I have the most up-to-date version

Comment: Galileo is a little old, so I'm not sure what issues you may run into in that particular setup.  What I can tell you is that eclipse *without* a CDT or otherwise ignoring the C files should have no trouble with this project - traditionally all of the ndk stuff has happened without eclipse's involvement, being handled instead by ndk-build.

Comment: Ok, I'm very new to this and slightly confused. Do you mean that the CDT is only to basically error check the code? The code that was given to me is already up and running on its own, so I think it should work fine. If I call the native methods in my Java code without the CDT, it will work?

Comment: Yes, you do not need the CDT.  It gives you things like error indications in the editor, and likely debugger integration, but the actual building is (or at least can be) done by the ndk-build script.

Comment: Just got rid of my CDT, no errors anymore and still have the library built. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is eclipse error. It simply does not understand your c and h files. Try to install CDT plugin, maybe after that the problems will eliminate.

Comment: Actually, I suspect the problem is having a generic CDT plugin that doesn't know about android; so it would have to either be removed, or configured to use the ndk includes rather than the host ones.

Comment: There is a preference in Eclipse in Android tab where you can specify path to your ndk. I do not know exactly, but maybe it's worth to specify it there and thus, eclipse will know about android ndk.

Comment: If this is an android-aware CDT, then that sounds like a good bet.  Hopefully it can deduce the include path for the selected target platform once told where to find the ndk, much like the java side finds the appropriate platform jar once given the path of the sdk.

Comment: I think I downloaded the correct CDT plugin. I searched Galileo in the Install New Software option, which is what I find everyone else online doing. My NDK path is set to my NDK's main folder. I wasn't sure if I needed to direct it somewhere more exact.